# Where does the choice of k = 51 for de Bruijn graphs of large genomes come from?

Tags: de-bruijn-graphs

*This question has also been asked on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9533382/)*

From hearsay I know that de Bruijn graphs of large genomes (e.g. human) are usually constructed with k = 51, or that k = 51 is at least a good initial choice.

I however am unable to find any source for this, does anyone know where it is coming from?

Comment: Not an answer. SGA is the first assembler I know that has a 51-mer default (more exactly ≥51bp overlap) but I am not sure if k=51 comes from SGA. Note that ALLPATHS-LG/DISCOVAR, arguably the best short-read dBG assembler for large genomes, uses k>100 for end-merged reads, so I don't think k=51 is necessarily an optimal choice.

Comment: Note that `k` should (must?) be odd to avoid kmers that are reverse-complement palindromes.